# update user column with session

Tags: php, mysql

I have delete option on my php page but I have added option to archive the data before delete but the same time I want update the user name with the person session user name.

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO c_archive_table(tech, eng, dr) SELECT tech, eng, dr FROM   `Com` WHERE `id`='$id'";
 $sql_user = "INSERT INTO  c_archive_table('','user','$_SESSION['username']') WHERE `id`='$id'";
 $sql_delete="DELETE FROM `Com` WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

so moving to archive and delete working but adding user Session to user column didn't work.

Comment: Look at the highlighting in the question above. It'll show you one possible issue.

Comment: Also, please fix the gaping SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont be an `INSERT` it will be an `UPDATE`

```
 $sql_user = "UPDATE c_archive_table SET 'user'='".$_SESSION['username']."' WHERE `id`='$id'";
```

Replace `user` column with whatever column name the `$_SESSION` name goes into

Comment: You'll need to replace the quotes around user with backticks, I think.

Comment: thanks, but some reason still didn't update the user name on sql `echo $_SESSION['username'];` display the user name but not sure why not saved on sql.

Comment: `$sql_user = "UPDATE c_archive_table SET 'user'='".$_SESSION['username']."' WHERE UPDATE c_archive_table.id='$id'";` did work! thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE);

// 1. Find the row in the existing table and get the contents
$query1 = '
SELECT
   `tech`,
   `eng`,
   `dr`
FROM `Cnom`
WHERE
   `id` = "'.$sql->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).'"
;';
   // Use real_escape_string to sanitize anything that the user could modify
$result1 = $sql->query($query1) or die ("<pre>Query failed:\n$query1</pre>");
   // die()ing with the query is always helpful for debugging
$row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc() or die ("<pre>No result returned for id {$_GET['id']}</pre>");

// 2. Insert the contents into the archive
$query2 = '
INSERT INTO `c_archive_table` (
   `user`,
   `tech`,
   `eng`,
   `dr`
)
VALUES (
   "'.$sql->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']).'",
   "'.$sql->real_escape_string($row1['tech']).'",
   "'.$sql->real_escape_string($row1['eng']).'",
   "'.$sql->real_escape_string($row1['dr']).'"
);';
$sql->query($query2) or die ("<pre>Query failed:\n$query2</pre>");

// 3. Delete from the original table
$query3 = '
DELETE FROM `Cnom`
WHERE
   `id` = "'.$sql->real_escape_string($_GET['id']).'"
;';
$sql->query($query3) or die ("<pre>Query failed:\n$query3</pre>");
```

That might be a good start, based on what I guess your database tables look like.

By the way, I'd recommend that, when diagnosing MySQL issues, that you do like in this example: write your queries in multiple lines with indents; and use the `die (string)` construct of PHP to print an error-producing query. You can then have a clear view of the query to see any obvious syntax errors, and MySQL can also tell you what line the error occurred on. You can also copy and paste the `die()`d query into phpMyAdmin.

---

More importantly, this is probably not the right setup. What you should have, rather than two redundant tables that carry almost the same information, is one table with a column `archived`. Then you just change `archived` to a boolean value (true) and check that whenever you're trying to access it.

For example (pseudocode):

```
if (accessing_all_records) {
   // Access all records that aren't archived
   $query = '
SELECT
   *
FROM `Cnom`
WHERE
   `archived` = 0
;';
}

if (inserting_new_record) {
   // Create a new record and set archived to 0 by default (better yet, give it a default value)
   $query = '
INSERT INTO `Cnom` (
   `field_1`,
   ...,
   `archived`
)
VALUES (
   value_1,
   ...,
   0
);';
}

if (archiving) {
   // Update the record and set the archived value to 1
   $query = '
UPDATE `Cnom`
SET
   `archived` = 1
WHERE
   `id` = id
;';
}
```